# paperclip not displaying medium or thumb in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm using paperclip with Rails 3.1. When I add the image, it shows me the original size but doesn't show me thumb or medium sizes:

Here is what I have in my view:

```
<%= image_tag @image.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
<%= image_tag @image.avatar.url(:medium) %>
```

image.rb

```
 has_attached_file :avatar, :whiny => false, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

UPDATE:

Here is the error I'm getting with `:whiny => true`

> Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/54/txjcl9l130j6dq73r37hf2c00000gn/T/stream20111213-9180-1plu1me.png[0]'
>   [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #
>
> Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/54/txjcl9l130j6dq73r37hf2c00000gn/T/stream20111213-9180-1plu1me.png[0]'
>   [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #
>   Rendered images/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)

Comment: Considering that you have `:whiny => false`, there could very likely be an exception occurring during the thumbnail creation process. Try setting `:whiny => true` and post any errors you encounter. My guess: image magic isn't installed, or Rails doesn't know where to find it because your `path` isn't set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that [Image Magick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php?ImageMagick=k0966f23mudvmtq7c5ionlbh30) is installed.

To see if its installed properly, go to a terminal session and type `which convert`. You should see a path to the executable.

Once that is done, you may need to add the path to your `environment.rb` file. For example, my `convert` is located at `/usr/local/bin/convert`. Now I've seen two different ways of setting your path for paperclip, try one or the other and see what works.

```
# specifically set the paperclip path
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/local/bin'

# set the path in general, might not be necessary
ENV['PATH'] = '/usr/local/bin:' + ENV['PATH']
```

Comment: I do have Image Magick installed. I see that convert is in /usr/local/bin and I also added ENV['PATH'] to environment.rb but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Ok. Can you run `identity foo.png` from the command line? Where "foo.png" is a real image on your computer. Just curious if the command works. It should echo out some information about the image.

Comment: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: Incompatible library version: identify requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 9.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: I fixed it by updated identify and convert from the ImageMagick binaries